# GitHub action - use secret in file?

Tags: github-actions

Is there any way I can use a GitHub action secret in a script within the action?
I my case I have a settings file  ( a *.toml file which does not accept environment variables) which needs a password. since I don't want to have it in my GitHub repo I thought it would be an option to do something like that in my action file

```
- name: Add PW to Config
  run: |
    sed -in "s/^password.*/password=$SERVER_PASSWORD/g" deploy.toml
```

but GitHub is cleverer then me and replaces the password with `***`
is there anything I can do here to use the secret in my action file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it with the [Find and Replace](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/find-and-replace) Action and it works well:

```yaml
name: 'write-secret-to-file'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Match and replace by Regex in the 'deploy.toml' file
      - name: Find and Replace
        uses: jacobtomlinson/gha-find-replace@v2
        with:
          find: "^password.*"
          replace: ${{ format('password={0}', secrets.SERVER_PASSWORD) }}
          regex: true
          include: 'deploy.toml'

      # Just for test purposes, to check if the file contains a secret value
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: my-artifact
          path: deploy.toml
```

Comment: that is so weird!! but hey - thank you so much for your answer - it indeed works!

Comment: @HannesF, actually, there is nothing weird, it's security concerns:)